# Manga where mc is summoned to another world but creates robots for a village only to leave

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I read a few chapters of this manga, and a specific part is when he makes a robot horse for a little girl to have fun. He also has a robot girl that he made in a space between time and reality where he is the successor of a female magician of Creation magic.

Comment: Where did you read this? When did you read this? In color or black and white? What art style? Could you tell what language it was in originally? Was there adult content? How did this guy get transported to the world? Did he actually die and reincarnate? Do you remember how he died?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be *[Magi Craft Meister](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Magi_Craft_Meister)*?

[image: Front cover of Magi Craft Meister]

> There is only one Magi Craft Meister in the world. After the death of the last Meister over one thousand years ago, Jin Nidou was transported to another world in order to succeed her will.
>
> After obtaining the knowledge of the Magi Craft Meister, Jin attempts to use a warp gate but it malfunctions, transporting him to an unknown world. Along with that, an automata he recently restored also uses the warp gate in order to search for her "father". Thus, the crafting journey of the new Magi Craft Meister begins!

Found by searching for `isekai manga robot horse "robot girl"` which led me to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/g9bmzz/looking_for_a_specific_manga/) where it was a suggestion.

Comment: Yes thanky thats the one i have been looking for this over a month 

Comment: Glad I could help.